# How to display the page login.html of bootstrap template using springboot?

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap template and spring boot , i have this  controller  :

```
package demo.controllers;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

import demo.connection.SingletonConnection;
import demo.dao.IDatabase;
import demo.dao.IEntities;
import demo.entities.DB;

@RestController

        @RequestMapping(value = "/")
        public class HomeController {

            @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.PUT})
            public String index{
                return "login";
            }

        }
```

An this is the form login.html in the  folder pages :

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form role="form">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                                <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

</body>
```

And this is the structure of my project

[image]

when i run the application with the path localhost:8080/ , it gives me  a black page  and not the view  but what i want me is to display the view :login wich is in the folder template/pages

Comment: Remove `Rest` from `@RestController`.

Comment: Now it gives me an other error wich is  This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu May 21 16:26:01 CEST 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: you can just return "login"; for displaying login page and if you want to redirect it then write a method in your controller for handling that

Comment: niledh virkar , i do what you say  i just return "login" but i have a blanck page i can't see the form that i code in the login page .I really need your help

Comment: sorry for late reply, is your problem solved? if not then can you edit your question with your project structure(like jsp files location) and jsp files

Comment: no it's not resolved i will edit the question right now

Comment: what is the url in the addr bar, after localhost:8080/ type?

Comment: there is nothing after localhost:8080/ ; it  should redirects  the to login page in the return

Comment: ok, so after redirecting the url is localhost:8080/ not localhost:8080/login right?

Comment: normally after redirecting it should attend the login page and the url will become localhost:8080/login.html but it's not the case :/

Comment: oh ok, are using Thymeleaf? like https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: no i am using bootsrap template you can see it in the structure if i correctly understand thymeleaf is default template that we can use with spring boot but if i choose another template oi don't need it!!!

Comment: Yes you are correct, you can use bootstrap css with thymeleaf also

Comment: I an new to bootstrap so it's enough :p i am in training and i am very pressed by time  .so what do you think can be the problem ?

Comment: I notice that i am using also angularjs with the html

Comment: Hi @ChawqiHajar Any update ? I have this problem also...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Spring Boot documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot), static resources can be placed under:

- /META-INF/resources/
- /resources/
- /static/
- /public/

I had a similar problem with HTML views under the *template* folder, they were not being loaded. I got it fixed just by accident when I added the thymeleaf starter to my dependencies. This starter has a view resolver (ThymeleafViewResolver) and it was able to load the files.

Probably to you moving the files to one of the folders listed above is a better solution.